# One-Time Pad Vulnerabilities

Tags: one-time-pad, key-reuse

- Why is it that a one time pad is vulnerable is the key is shorter than the message?
- I know that if a key is reused across multiple plaintexts, you can XOR two existing ciphertexts to get the pad, but I'm not entirely sure how this works in practice.

Any help/ explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the key bits are shorter then the message you need to reuse some part of the previous key bits. If this is known, and we can assume by [Kerckhoff Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle),
then the enemy can crib-drag on the same message. A more dedicated enemy will always try this case and also the reuse case; the same key is used with another message, too.

As an example;

```
m = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
k = KkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkKkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

where $x$ represents the message bits, $k$ represents the key bits and $K$ represents the start of the key bits. Divide the message into parts;

```
m1 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
k  = Kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
m2 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
k  = Kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

now, execute crib-dragging.